# $am+bn = 36$; What can you say about $gcd(m, n)$

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $a, b, m,$ and $n$ be integers and suppose that $am+bn = 36$. What can
>   you say about $gcd(m, n)$?

The professor said the question has **one answer** and he gave me this hint.

**HINT:** $gcd(m, n)$ has the property that it divides both $m$ and $n$. What does imply about $gcd(m, n)$ and $am+bn$?

**My answers:**
$gcd(a, b) = gcd(m, n)$. And $gcd(m, n)$ and $gcd(a, b)$ are both divisible by $36$.

Uhm... I'm not sure what hint implies and if my answer is correct..

Comment: First part of your answer makes no sense.  Since you don’t make any use of $36$ you could make the same claim about any four numbers, which is unreasonable.

Comment: The second half of your answer sounds wrong but you might have just written it carelessly backwards.  Do you really mean “divisible by 36”, like for instance you are saying 72 would be a reasonable value for $\gcd(m,n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is
$$\gcd(m,n)|36$$
This is because $am+bn$ is divisible by $\gcd(m,n)$.

Comment: Uhm the answer should be one "sentence".

Comment: Should I answer it like am+bn is divisible by gcd(m, n)?? And can you state your reason?

Comment: @John The third line is the reason. The middle line says that the gcd divides $36$, and you can combine that into one sentence with the reason.

Comment: ok thanks, Matt

Comment: @John No problem.

Answer (score 0):

No.  It's the other way around.   Since $gcd(m,n)$ divides both $m$ and $n$, it divides $36$.

That's about all that can be said...